# TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_react___default.a.createContext is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I've been having this issue since i upgraded react-bootstrap Ive searched for possible solutions but nothing seems to work.

I think the issue is with the bootstrap theme
as I've read that the bootstrap theme was removed in the upgraded bootstrap version 4. how do i solve this?

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-4-theme/dist/bootstrap-theme.css';
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
```

Dependencies:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-4-theme": "^1.0.2",
    "glyphicons": "^0.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
```

Comment: Are you by chance using the React Context API?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this Mark?

Answer (score 0):

[This bug report](https://github.com/hasura/react-check-auth/issues/24) mentions a version mismatch, needing ^16.3 for react and react-dom. You have met those requirements, but perhaps there is another component, such as react-scripts, that needs to be updated as well. I previously ran into this problem and resolved it with:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
  "react": "^16.12.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
  "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
  "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
  "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
  "redux": "^3.7.2",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
}
```